# Why I use Data Payload JSON FCM. It doesn't work to get notification in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
{"data":{"user":"michael"},"to": "<FCM KEY USER>"}
```

I don't know how it works in any device, For example. I was trying to add handlerMessage like this

```
Future<void> backgroundhandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 print("$message");
}
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundhandler);
```

but, if I use notification payload after data payload. it works. why did it work?

Comment: thank you very much to help me fixing my pronouns @Praveen. sorry. if my language isn't too good